# When can we merge multiple integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

In an exercise we had to calculate $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-(x_1^2+x_2^2)}dx_1dx_2$ and deduce $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}dx$

To do this we calculate the double integral using polar coordinates, which gives $\pi$.

The second one is calculated like this:

$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}dx=\sqrt{\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x_1^2}dx_1\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x_2^2}dx_2}=\sqrt{\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-(x_1^2+x_2^2)}dx_1dx_2}=\sqrt{\pi}$

Why were we allowed to merge those two integrals?

Comment: It's a general result in mathematics called Fubini's theorem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem.  The integrands are both positive, the theorem can be used here.

Answer (score 3):

Because:$$\int\int f(x)g(y)\;dy\;dx=\int f(x)\int g(y)\;dy\;dx=\int g(y)\;dy\times \int f(x)\;dx$$

Here $f(x)=g(x)=e^{-x^2}$.

Comment: You can look at $\int g(y) \; \mathrm{d}y$ as a constant with respect to $x$, which is why you can pull it out of the integral sign, much like you would, say, with a factor of $2$.

Comment: What's "$\times$" here?

Comment: Multiplication. As in $20=4\times5$. Both integrals on RHS are (if they exist) real numbers, and also the double integral on LHS is a real number (in your case it equals $\pi$).

Answer (score 0):

note that what you had was:
$$\int_a^b\int_a^bf(x)f(y)dxdy$$
note that each function is independent and so we get:
$$\left[F(x)\right]_a^b\left[F(y)\right]_a^b=\left(\left[F(z)\right]_a^b\right)^2$$

Answer (score 0):

If the limits of integration are independent of the variables...

$\int_a^b\int_c^d f(x)g(y)\ dy\ dx = (\int_a^b f(x)\ dx)(\int_c^d g(y)\ dy)$